# Expressjs Route contains weird characters

Tags: node.js, json, rest, http, express

What could possibly be the reason for expressjs route to contain the following data? I am expecting it to return JSON data. I am making an ajax call to the server(expressjs) which gives me the below data with weird characters. Is this data gzipped? I have set the headers and contentType as follows:

```
headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"}
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
```

�=O�0�b��K�)�%7�܈9���G��%NOU���O'6��k�~6��S.���,��/�wأ%6�K�)��e�

The HTTP response is as follows:

```
General:
Request URL: http://localhost/expressRoute.js
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers:
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 29396
Content-Type: application/javascript
Date: Thu, 22 Nov 2018 00:50:36 GMT
ETag: "72d4-57b124e0c372e"
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Last-Modified: Tue, 20 Nov 2018 05:57:12 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.34 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0i PHP/7.2.10

Request Headers:
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://localhost/index.html
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Post the full HTTP response.

Comment: I have added the HTTP response in the question.

Comment: I don't see the HTTP response with type json...